# Rendering components that are rendered in different locations

Tags: reactjs, dom

component.js has 4 components that are each rendered in different section of the page:

**component.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(<ComponentLeft1/>, document.getElementById("colLeft1"));
ReactDOM.render(<ComponentRight1/>, document.getElementById("colRight1"));
ReactDOM.render(<ComponentLeft2/>, document.getElementById("colLeft2"));
ReactDOM.render(<ComponentRight2/>, document.getElementById("colRight2"));

export default {ComponentLeft1,ComponentRight1,ComponentLeft2, ComponentRight2};
```

Is there a way that I could use these components in another file so that they would render same way they render in **component.js** or somehow combine those 4 components but still be able to render them like they are currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the component where ever you want and use it by giving proper path

For example :
If you want to import ** ComponentLeft1** to some other file then simply import it like:

```
import {ComponentLeft1} from './componentjs'
```

and finally, use it in that file as

```
<ComponentLeft1 />
```

Comment: Is there a way I could render them all at once? Like with certain path from url? For example www.website.com/page and it would point to component.js file and render everything in there?

Comment: You can make use of react-router. For more details head here - https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf